# Assign varible in gnu make from Python sys.exit string

Tags: python, makefile, sys

I would like to assign a variable in gnu make to the `sys.exit()` from a Python script.  A simple Python script, let's call it string_gen.py, might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
    
def string_gen():
    return "string_file.txt"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(string_gen())
```

In the make file, a target might look like

```
.PRECIOUS: $(FILE_STRINGS)
$(STRING_DICT): $(STRING_DIR)/string_gen.py $(PYTHON)
    $(V)if [[ $(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT) ]]; then STRING_FILE=$($(PYTHON) $< $(@D)); fi
    $(V)if [[ $(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT) ]]; then $(PYTHON) $(STRING_DIR)/report.py $(STRING_FILE); fi
```

I would like to assign `STRING_FILE` to the result of sys.exit() when set in the Python script.  I can run the report.py from the command line and it does print "string_file.txt" to the console, but this result is not saved to the `STRING_FILE` variable in the make file.  Is there a way to pass the result of running a Python script and assign it to variable in gnu make?

Edit: The makefile is to provide some context and doesn't present the full makefile.  I took out just one small, very small, part in attempts to show what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why are you using `sys.exit` to provide something that doesn't look like an error message?

Comment: @chepner, I was using it since I didn't know of any other way to return the string, hence the reason for the question.

Comment: OK; the answer, then, is *don't* use it :) Just use `print`.

Answer (score 1):

You have many many issues here:

```
.PRECIOUS: $(FILE_STRINGS)
```

I'm assuming this is related to some part of the makefile you haven't shown us; it has no relevance to the recipe below.

```
$(STRING_DICT): $(STRING_DIR)/string_gen.py $(PYTHON)
        $(V)if [[ $(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT) ]]; then STRING_FILE=$($(PYTHON) $< $(@D)); fi
```

First note if `$(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT)` expands to the empty string this will be a syntax error.  You should quote it, for example `'$(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT)'`.

Second you should not use `[[ ... ]]`: make always runs `/bin/sh` and this condition syntax is not POSIX: it's supported by bash and some other shells but not by all POSIX shells.  So if you run it on a system where `/bin/sh` is a strictly POSIX shell this will fail.  You should either use the POSIX form, like `[ -n "$(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT)" ]` or else if you want to require that anyone using your makefile use bash, you should add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to your makefile.

Third, this syntax is wrong: `$($(PYTHON) $< $(@D))`  This will expand the *make variable* named `python .../string-gen.py ...` which is certainly empty/not set.
The `$` character is special to make so if you want to pass that character to the shell, for command substitution, you have the escape it by writing it as `$$`.

Fourth, as others have pointed out python `sys.exit()` writes to stderr and command substitution captures only stdout, so this won't work.

Fifth, this assigns the *shell variable* `STRING_FILE`: when writing makefiles it's critical to keep firmly in your mind the difference between make variables and shell variables.  They are not the same at all.  Recipes run in the shell and can only set shell variables.

Sixth, every logical line in a recipe is run in a separate shell which means that when the logical line ends the shell exits and all variables, etc. you have set will disappear.  If you want the same variable to be used across multiple shell commands then you have to put them all into the same logical line.

```
        $(V)if [[ $(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT) ]]; then $(PYTHON) $(STRING_DIR)/report.py $(STRING_FILE); fi
```

As above, `$(STRING_FILE)` here is a *make* variable reference, but in the previous line you set the *shell* variable `STRING_FILE`.  Which, anyway, is gone because the shell in the previous line exited.

You need to write this as:

```
$(STRING_DICT): $(STRING_DIR)/string_gen.py $(PYTHON)
        $(V)if [ -n '$(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT)' ]; then \
               STRING_FILE=$$($(PYTHON) $< $(@D) 2>&1); \
               $(PYTHON) $(STRING_DIR)/report.py $$STRING_FILE; \
           fi
```

Or, if you wanted to do it with less typing:

```
$(STRING_DICT): $(STRING_DIR)/string_gen.py $(PYTHON)
        $(V)[ -z '$(IF_BUILD_STRING_DICT)' ] \
              || $(PYTHON) $(STRING_DIR)/report.py $$($(PYTHON) $< $(@D) 2>&1)
```

The only reason I can think of for wanting to print the filename to stderr is that you have other text going to stdout.  If that's the case (you don't show that in your example) then you should use `3>&2 2>&1 1>&3` instead of just `2>&1`.

Comment: you would be correct as there are missing contexts within the makefile, but I can't post it.  I took the original makefile, modified it enough to give context of the idea what I was trying to do.  I didn't realize the sys.exit() was going to stderr.  I had used `$($(PYTHON) $< $(@D))` from another posting I found online.  I will update the post state the makefile is only to provide some context and not the full makefile

Comment: As I said, there's no way you can use `$($(PYTHON) $< $(@D))` successfully in a makefile recipe.  If some other posting was using that, then that posting doesn't work :)

Comment: So, the only way to return the string is using stderr and not other way?  I tried using an environment variable that is set in the Python script, but that doesn't work since since once the script competed that environment variable no longer exist.  Though about setting a variable in .bashrc, but then would have to check variable exist and modify it.

Comment: Well, you could obviously use stdout instead of stderr, by changing your `sys.exit(string_gen())` to be `print(string_gen())`.  However as you've discovered, there's no way for the child process to set anything in the environment of the parent process.  There's no way to send information (other than the exit code) to the parent except through printing it for the parent to capture or writing it to a file for the parent to open and read in.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution, unfortunately this didn't work.  STRING_FILE appears to be empty.  I changed the line to `$(ECHO) "Stringfile: " $(STRING_FILE);` and it only prints out "Stringfile: ".   I have given up on this approach and just pass the directory, which is the `$(@)` and search for the file extension, csv.

Comment: You can't use `$(STRING_FILE)`.  That's a reference to a _make variable_.  You are setting a _shell variable_ (all recipes are run by the shell, and so all variables assignments in a recipe must be shell variable assignments).  That's my seventh point above and if you examine my suggested solutions you'll see that I wrote it as `$$STRING_FILE`, which is a reference to a shell variable, not `$(STRING_FILE)`.  If you use my suggested solutions as I wrote them, they will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the sys.exit documentation:

```
any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1.
```

Your output is printed to stderr, but you are reading from stdout.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of your program is to simply output the name of a file, just use `print`. A string argument to `sys.exit` is intended as an error message, and is written to standard error instead of standard output (which is what the command substitution captures).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    
def string_gen():
    return "string_file.txt"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(string_gen())
```